# mitsuba 0.5.0 wouldn't import collada

Tags: import, collada

Importer says:

> Critical collada error: daeStandardURIResolver::ResolveElement() -
>   failed to resolve file:/path/result.dae#whiteMaterial

I tried to remove `library_effects` and `library_materials`, then imported correctly. How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this error, it happens when you want use material which don't declared in `library_materials` and `library_effects`